# Is there a cakePHP two way encryption method which produces a "legible" output?

Tags: cakephp

how are you?

I'm writing a "forgot your password" function in cakePHP. User passwords are hashed into the databases, so I have to make the user pick a new password.

The form in the view asks for 2 values, "email" and "new_password". The function checks that the e-mail exists, and then sends an e-mail with a confirmation link which looks like:

http://mysite.com/users/confirm_forgot/#USERID#/#HASHED_USER_ID/#PASSWORD#/#HASHED_PASSWORD#

Once the user clicks on that link, the function then checks that the parameters (#USERID# and #PASSWORD) match with their hashed versions.

The problem is that #PASSWORD# travels with no encryption (plain text), and I don't like it, so **I wan't to apply a 2 way encryption to that parameter that produces an output similar to a UUID**.

I know about the *Security::cipher* function, but it created non "legible" characters, such as "�I3:" for the original "1234".

---

- **Rounding it up:**

  Is there a **cakePHP** built in method that will allow me to encrypt a text into something that *looks* like a UUID (such as *FBBD4D1E-B46C-0418-15793119526DB242 FBBD4D1F-F56E-0D13-39730810BCEB0CD3*) but that I can later on decrypt?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to include the plain-text password? You are already including the hashed password, so just compare that with the hashed password stored in the DB.

Comment: Hello Joseph, how are you? That wouldn't work, since I want to CHANGE the password, and the user has to confirm it (I can't change the password until the user enters his e-mail address and clicks on the link) hence, the password stored in the DB is NOT the new one, but the old one, the one he can't remember, heh.

Comment: Could you not include the hash of the new and old password. Compare the old password hash with the one in your DB, and insert the new password hash? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: Or maybe I'm not explaining my self! ;-) the scenario is: User forgets his password, so he goes to the "forgot" section and enters his e-mail address and a new password (which is not stored anywhere). In order to verify that the user who requested the new password is actually the owner of the e-mail address, I send a confirm link... this confirm link has to send me back the password the user picked, since it wasn't stored anywhere (I can't store it in the database because I don't know if it was a valid request yet or if it was a malicious user). So, I want to encrypt that password I send back.

Comment: And of course, it has to be a 2 way encryption, because I have to know exactly which new password has the user picked! Thanks for the interest, by the way.

Comment: Aah I see. In this case you want to store the new hashed password temporarily somewhere in a table along with a GUID, and then just put the GUID in the email. When the user clicks the link look you can get the password with the GUID. Make sure to clear out your table of temporary passwords frequently, e.g. every 12 hours.

Comment: Right, I know the workarounds of it. But out of curiosity, I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish my original question with cakePHP. Thanks anyways!

Comment: NP. Sorry not too familiar with cakePHP (just plain ol' PHP). Hopefully someone with more experience in that field can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to add a base_64 encode to the "illegible" output it generates. D'oh.